# how to convert DBmetadata in NSdata?

Tags: ios, objective-c, metadata, nsdata, dropbox-api

```
-(void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedFile:(NSString*)destPath contentType:(NSString*)contentType metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata
```

- this function of dropbox api is giving me metadata. I want to convert
  this metadata as NSData to send through the following line for
  web service

  [body appendData:metadata]

so its giving me pointer warning.

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'DBMetadata *' to parameter of type
>   'NSData * _Non null'

how to resolve this?

Comment: Is `DBMetadata` NSCoding compliant?

Comment: @Larme Sorry, i don't know anything about this.